# Can I use jQuery to hide an element on a specific html page?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have an h2 in my header that is displayed on index.html, but for about.html I need to hide it, is there a way with jQuery to basically say, "if about.html hide element"?

Here is the HTML code, I need to hide the h2.

```
<header>
  <div class="header-container">
    <div>
      <h2 id="header-name">Matthew Pichola</h2>
      <p>mp@icloud.com</p>
    </div>
    <p class="about-link">about me</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just remove those `h2` lines from about.html? To me it is a bit strange to hide/show some elements base on the file name.

Comment: I am importing one header file into each page to maintain consistency so it made more sense for me to do it this way

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, using jQuery like this;

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/deploy/index')) {
    $('#header-name').hide();
  } else{
    $('#header-name').show();
  }
```

Comment: Or in one line `$('#header-name').toggle(window.location.href.indexOf('/deploy/index'));`